# How can I mod rewrite all traffic to index.php but also to a backend directory?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My directory is set up as follows:

```
root directory:
  html:
      index.php
      .htaccess
  server (code):
      site:
          index.php
          test.php
```

Requests go into html/index.php, and then the server gets initiated in the backend.  Calling `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` yields the following for `http://localhost/`

```
Request URL : /index.php
```

This is correct, because I can then add on site/index.php.  However, I want to also do `http://localhost/test` and have it changed to /site/test.php.  The following is what happens when calling `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` for `http://localhost/test`

```
Request URL : /testindex.php
```

What should happen is `Request URL : /test` so then I can add on the site/test.php myself.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files / Directories cannot be accessed outside the document_root. The simple solution is to update the index.php as a router. Then the router needs to include the corresponding files, if it exists. Otherwise you need to handle the file not exists situation, such as response 404 error.

You may need to update this .htaccess to redirect all the request to index.php:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Then, you can parse the route in index.php:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['route'])) {
        $route = $_GET['route'];
        if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/../site/' . $route)) {
            include __DIR__.'/../site/' . $route;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Everything on the site hits html/index.php first (it sets up the entire server), then in html/index.php I run the server class, which does $requestURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  However, using the mod_rewrite I still do not get the desired results (not even index.php?route=$1).  Weirdly enough using the whole name works ... localhost/test.php will show correct results: Request URL : /test.php, but  localhost/test will show Request URL : /testindex.php

Comment: you may need to modify the router so that, when the request url does not end with .php, append this to the end.